# Android resolution always using x-large drawables in any device

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I am developing an Android application. I am trying to deploy it in 3 devices with different resolutions and these are Samsung pocket GT-S5300 android 2.3.6, Samsung young GT-S6310 android 4.1.2, PIpo M8 tablet android 4.1.1. I am having a big problem when it comes to deploying the app because in my 2 samsung devices they're using the layout-xlarge instead of my default layout. Icons appears bigger and I think that they are all using the xlarge instead of the normal one. I don't know why. Please help me. I really want these 3 different resolutions to have different layout and drawables sizes.

Here is my manifest

```
   android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

[image]

all of this layout folder contains same layouts

samsung pocket appearance

[image]

Pipo M8 appearance

[image]

Comment: show your folder structure with a screenshot

Comment: @PontusBacklund i have updated it now. look

Comment: @PontusBacklund see my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some general tips and ideas:

firstly, why are you targeting API 8? you should be targeting current versions of android, which is while writing 19 (you can still have minSDK 8).

Use dp qualifiers such as `layout-sw600dp layout-sw720dp` to cover small and large tablets.

Also I'm noticing there's nothing in your xhdpi folder which is getting pretty standard on most new devices. I'm hoping you know how to format these images in qualifier folders? for example mdpi is basically 72dpi as your computer monitor hdpi resources should be around 1.5 times larger than mdpi resources and so forth. This is probably where your problem lies.

Comment: Yeah. i know you're gonna tell me that but i did targeting lower version of android because if i'm going to target lets say API 17 with minSdk 8 and deploy it in my Pipo M8 4.1.1 android, my app crashes during login. i don't know why. can you help me with this?

Comment: but it's not crashing in android 2.3.6

Comment: hmm the target should have no influence on an app crash, post the stacktrace of this when it happens. Was it your drawable sizes that was faulty on your graphic problem?

Comment: I can't post the stacktrace because the error happens on tablet. When i run the app via emulator the app is not crashing because it uses android 2.2 UI.

Comment: yes. my drawables appears big in my samsung pocket. It's just good in tablet Pipo M8.